# Plugin Development for CLion: How to add a method call to an existing method

Tags: java, clion, intellij-plugin

I am currently learning about how to write plugins for IntelliJ IDEs. I am especially interested in writing plugins for CLion.
I am trying to find a way how to add a method call to the top of the body of an existing method.
I already found a way to get the Function Definitions  in a File.

```java
psiFile.accept(new PsiRecursiveElementWalkingVisitor(){
    @Override
    public void visitElement(PsiElement element) {
        super.visitElement(element);
        //OCFunctionDefinition test = new OCFunctionDefinition();
        if(element instanceof OCFunctionDefinition){
            infoBuilder.append(element.getText()).append("\n");
            element.add(elementAtCarret);
        }
    }
});
```

I read in the documentation that I can create new PsiFiles via PsiFileFactory.
For Java I could get a Factory with:

```java
PsiElementFactory factory = JavaPsiFacade.getInstance(project).getElementFactory();
```

Is there also a factory for c++? Something like:

```java
PsiElementFactory factory = OcPsiFacade.getInstance(project).getElementFactory();
```

Also is this approach in general the right one, for adding a method call to an existing method body?

Comment: There's `com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.util.OCElementFactory` with a bunch of static methods in it. I hope, this helps.

Comment: @EldarAbusalimov Thanks. I will take a look at it.